# What brand and model is the briefcase used by the Observers?

Tags: fringe, costume

In the interest of possible cosplay, what brand and model is the briefcase used by the Observers? What if any modifications have been done?
It looks like some sort of vintage Samsonite, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact model.

[image: a row of Observer briefcases]

Comment: It appears to be a 1970s Samsonite briefcase with the label removed; http://www.sybarites.com/2009/09/thom-browne-attache-case-by-samsonite-black-label/

Comment: This is a genuine one from the same period - http://i.stack.imgur.com/J6qC7.jpg

Comment: Actually, I had found those as well [through reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/fringe/comments/15w1qk/where_can_i_buy_an_observer_briefcase/). But neither is shown as the briefcases are often shown as they are on the show: closed and from the side, showing a characteristic 'Y' with an elongated descender (as it were).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a 60s Samsonite Briefcase.

[image]

Note the open 'Y' at the top of the side, and the two studs either side of it.

Comment: Can you offer any confirmation that it's the same one (as opposed to one that is merely similar)?

Comment: @Richard still looking for definitive proof, will edit my answer when I find it. At the moment it's just just based on comparing footage of the briefcase (edited my answer to make that more evident).